# Is every positive semi-definite matrix a controllability Grammian?

Tags: linear-algebra, control-theory

Given a stable matrix $A$ (i.e., $A$ has eigenvalues with negative real parts) and a matrix $B$, the (infinite horizon) [controllability Grammian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Controllability_Gramian) $W_{\rm c}(A,B)$ is defined as $$W_{\rm c}(A,B) = \int_0^{\infty} e^{At} B B^T e^{A^T t}$$ 
Clearly the controllability Grammian is always positive semi-definite. I'm wondering about the converse: is every positive semi-definite matrix a controllability Grammian? Specifically, given a $W \succeq 0$ can we always find $A,B$ such that $W=W_{\rm c}(A,B)$?

Comment: Could you give some references in order that we can answer you more thoroughly, for example in connection with forms of Sylvester equation. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

For every $W_c$ real, symmetric and positive semidefinite let its Cholesky decomposition 
$$W_c=L L^T$$
with $L$ a lower triangular matrix with real and nonnegative diagonal entries. Then, selecting 
$$A=-\rho\mathbb{I}\\
B=\sqrt{2\rho}L$$
with $\rho>0$ we have that
$$e^{-\rho\mathbb{I}t}=e^{-\rho t}\mathbb{I}$$
and therefore
$$\int_0^{\infty}{e^{At}BB^Te^{A^Tt}dt}=\int_0^{\infty}{e^{-\mathbb{I}\rho t}(\sqrt{2\rho}L)(\sqrt{2\rho}L)^Te^{-\mathbb{I}\rho t}}dt=2\rho\bigg(\int_0^{\infty}{e^{-2\rho t}dt}\bigg) LL^T=W_c$$

Comment: Can you edit this answer to fix the missing symbol ($\phi$)? Also the statement,

$$ {e^{ - \rho \phi t}} =  - {e^{ - \rho t}}\phi $$

is not obvious.

Comment: @IvanAbraham Thank you, there is a typo in the identity that has been corrected to $e^{-\rho\mathbb{I}t}=e^{-\rho t}\mathbb{I}$.. By $\mathbf{I}$ we denote the identity matrix of order $n$. The specific property does not hold for all matrices but it is true for the identity matrix since $e^{-\rho\mathbb{I}t}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{\frac{(-\rho t)^k\mathbb{I}^k}{k!}}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{\frac{(-\rho t)^k}{k!}\mathbb{I}}=e^{-\rho t}\mathbb{I}$.